# Tidyverse commands are becoming deprecated: T test inside a summarise , then report all results

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, broom

I use *tidyverse* (and its environment) almost every day and from time to time I have to come back to previous/old analyses. Unfortunately, it's not easy to keep up the track of the changes that have been made to the package.

This script is pretty functional and it performs what I want (it is used inside a function with other commands)

```
ds <- data.frame(result = rnorm(100,5,2),
                 time = c("1","2"))
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

ds %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("result"),
               funs(list(tidy(t.test(. ~ time, paired=TRUE))))) %>% map(1)
```

I know this is not the most elegant syntax. Now, this message comes after the command:

funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:

```
  # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

All my attempt to fix it gives me a message...

```
> ds %>% 
+   summarise_at(vars("result"),
+                lst(tidy(t.test(. ~ time, paired=TRUE)))) %>% map(1)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ time) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable '.'
> ds %>% 
+   summarise_at(vars("result"),
+                list(list(tidy(t.test(. ~ time, paired=TRUE))))) %>% map(1)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ time) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable '.'
> ds %>% 
+   summarise_at(vars("result"),
+                list(list(tidy(~ t.test(. ~ time, paired=TRUE))))) %>% map(1)
Error: No tidy method for objects of class formula
```

So.. **first** question: Any clue about fixing it?
**second**: where can I follow these (constant) updates?
**Three**: I use tidyverse because I enjoy the way it deals with commands. It is pretty intuitive, but I see as an important side effect this constantly changes ... Should I try to move all my routines to R base (Probably, R base will not change its function ...)?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
ds <- data.frame(result = rnorm(100,5,2),
                 time = c("1","2"))

library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

ds %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("result"),
               list(~ list(tidy(t.test(. ~ time, paired=TRUE))))) %>% map(1)
#> $result
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>   estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1   -0.719     -1.77  0.0823        49    -1.53    0.0955 Paire~
#> # ... with 1 more variable: alternative <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>